# Term by term differentiability of Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence, laurent-series

I have a question about one of the solutions to an exercise from Serge Lang's Introduction to Complex Analysis. The context of the question is

[image]

and the question, including the given answer is

[image]

**My Question:** Why does it converge uniformly on $s \leq |z| \leq S$ rather than on $r \leq |z| \leq R$?

I understand how the uniform convergence implies the term by term differentiation but I do not understand why it converges uniformly on a slightly smaller ananullus rather than the one it is defined on.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, for instance, the Laurent series of $\frac1{1-z}$ on $D_1(0)$ is$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n,$$which converges uniformly on any closed disk $\overline{D_r(0)}$ when $r<1$, but not on $D_1(0)$. Also, the Laurent series of $\frac1{1-z}$ on $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|>1\}$ is$$-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}z_n,$$which converges uniformly on any annulus $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid r\leqslant|z|\leqslant R\}$ with $1<r<R$, but not on the annulus $\{z\in\Bbb C|1<|z|<\infty\}$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have a question. Doesn't the question already tell you that the Laurent series exist and so can't you assume they converge on the given annulus?

Comment: Yes, they do. But they don't have to converge uniformly. Just like both series from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think I am not understanding something correctly. I understand why the first one won't converge on the closed disk of radius 1 but I can't understand why it won't uniformly converge on the open disc of radius 1 as you have written?

Comment: Because each function $\sum_{n=0}^Nz^n$ is bounded in $D_1(0)$, but $\frac1{1-z}$ is unbounded there. When a sequence of bounded functions converges uniformly, its sum is also bounded.

Comment: I think I understand. Just to recap, the reason it is a smaller annulus comes from the fact that convergence does not imply uniform convergence?

Comment: That is correct. And also because on any smaller annulus we *do* have uniform convergence.

Comment: Is this as a result of Dini's Theorem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126702/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-maths-wizzard).